# compose new model objects[recursively] of a complex model object(inside viewmodel), from properties of view in MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have view class which is called Client, its view model is ClientViewModel. ClientViewModel is has a model object ClientInfo. This ClientInfo [Model] is complex object, which has properties of Model classes called Client & ClientProfile.

I have bound the properties of my UI elements in View, like as follows, (I use xxx.yyy.zzz to get to the property)

```
 <Label Content="First Name:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,5,0,4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="26" Width="70" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,7,0,4" Name="firstNameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=ClientInfo.Client.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
                <Label Content="Last Name:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,3,0,6" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="26" Width="69" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,5,0,6" Name="lastNameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=ClientInfo.Client.LastName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
.. 
<Button Content="Save" Height="24" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"   Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Cursor="Hand" Margin="549,10,10,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.137,-1.804" />
```

ClientViewModel:

```
[Export(typeof(ClientViewModel))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ClientViewModel : NotificationObject
{

    private readonly IClientService clientService;

    private ClientInfo clientInfoModel;
    private string currentState;
    public DelegateCommand<object> SubmitCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand<object> UpdateCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand<object> LoadCommand { get; private set; }

    [Import]
    public ClientInfo ClientInfoModel
    {
        get { return this.clientInfoModel; }
        set
        {
            clientInfoModel = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ClientInfoModel);
        }
    }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ClientViewModel(IClientService clientService)
    {
        this.clientService = clientService;


        this.SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.Submit);
        this.UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.Update);
        this.LoadCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.Load);
    }

    private void Load(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Update(object obj)
    {
        //update
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Submit(object obj)
    {
        string s = this.ClientInfoModel.ClientBasic.FirstName;//<--- this where i get the NPE exception
    }

    public string ViewName
    {
        get { return "Client Details"; }
    }

    public string CurrentState
    {
        get
        {
            return this.currentState;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.currentState == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.currentState = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CurrentState);
        }
    }

    public bool CanSubmit
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void Submit()
    {
        this.CurrentState = "Submitting";
        //this.clientRepository.SaveClientAsync(this.ClientInfoModel, result => { SaveClient(); });

    }

    private object SaveClient()
    {
        this.CurrentState = "Saving";

        return null;
    }
}
```

ClientInfo (Model):

```
public class ClientInfo : DomainObject
    {
        public Client ClientBasic { get; set; }

        public ClientProfile Profile { get; set; }
    }
```

Client (Model):

```
public class Client : DomainObject
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        ....
    }
```

In submit command invocation:

```
private void Submit(object obj)
        {
            ClientInfo ci = new ClientInfo();
            ci.Client <-- (here i would want to get the new Client obj assigned from properties?)
            ci.ClientProfile <---(same as above)
        }
```

View has submit button to save, on save command. I have to save new client object calling some services.

Issue here is that, I need to fill ClientInfo model with new Client() & new ClientProfile() objects. How can do that with this setup I am having.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, so in your submit button you want to create a new ClientInfo object which is a direct copy of the current Model you have? why not just do `ci.ClientBasic = clientInfoModel.ClientBasic;` and `ci.Profile = clientInfoModel.Profile;`. If your bindings are working fine. Then your Model should have the updated data and you can access the Model in the VM which is what holds it in the first place

Comment: @Viv i have tried that option but it does not work, i get null pointer exception. eg ci.ClientBasic = ClientInfo.ClientBasic; NPE is thrown on ClientInfo is null.

Comment: BTW: I am assuming that the ViewModel has a property called ClientInfo which exposes clientInfoModel?

Comment: @kbird looking at your VM implementation, where and when exactly is the Model created. where do you have code along the lines of `ClientInfoModel = new ClientInfo();`. I dont see any constructor / property injection or a direct creation in the VM which probably explains why the Model is null when you try to access it's children in your submit method.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few points here which I would do differently. However, in general with what you've posted everything is fine, there must be some mistake in the bits that you haven't posted. Please post the complete ViewModel class and explain how you pass the M to the VM and the VM to the V and I'll have another look at it.

If `ClientInfo` is null when `Submit(..)` is executed, that means that your ViewModel doesn't have a model. There must be something wrong with the assignment of the `ClientInfo` on your ViewModel. Try to set a breakpoint in `ClientInfos` set accessor and see whether it is set once and only once. Try to set a breakpoint in, for example, `FirstName`s set accessor and see whether it gets hit when you enter the name in your UI. Are there any BindingErrors shown in the output console?

That being said, are you sure that you want to do what you are trying at all? If you create a new `ClientInfo` class, and assign the properties `Client` and `ClientProfile` from another `ClientInfo` class, your two `ClientInfo` objects point to the exact same `Client` and `ClientProfile` object. As `ClientInfo` only has these two properties, I can think of reason why you would duplicate the `ClientInfo` object. you can just as good use the original object which is your ViewModel's Model...

Secondly, your ViewModel exposes the Model directly, which is not actually the point of a ViewModel, especially when you end up with chained bindings like

```
Text="{Binding Path=ClientInfo.Client.FirstName}"
```

The ViewModels core competency is to aggregate the data and allow easy binding from the View. I would expose a `FirstName`, `LastName`, etc. property on the ViewModel and let the ViewModel figure out where to take the data from and push the data to. Remember that you want to keep the View independent of any implementation details in the background.

Maybe these two suggestions already solve or avoid the problem altogether. Otherwise please feel free to post more context and I'll have a look again.

**EDIT**

In your ViewModel, I would expect something like

```
ClientInfoModel = clientService.GetClientInfo(...);
```

You inject the service, but where do you initialize `clientInfoModel`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I will post the complete view model. But I accept the fact the to keep the view independent from viewmodel implementation.

Comment: just updated the full view model, have a look when you have time

Comment: @Marc "your ViewModel exposes the Model directly, which is not actually the point of a ViewModel" - I don't agree with that soz. It's perfectly valid for a VM to expose the Model as a property than wrap every single property from the Model in the VM as a pass-thru to the View which not only adds to code-duplication but adds to further replication on every layout(1 VM per View). MVVM Helper libraries like MVVM Light expose `ObservableObject` which are perfect to inherit Models from to have the base class give them the INPC implementation.

Comment: @Marc even if someone told me I absolutely as a constraint should not be implementing INPC on the Model for whatever reason, then I'd have a service wrapping the Model with INPC and have this service in all the VM's than have pass-thru properties directly in the VM's just to future-proof and not have code-duplication across multiple VM's. Yes we could do the same thing by making a baseclass VM and inherit each VM from it than a service but I find composition better than inheritance for this particular thing. Just my opinion.

Comment: @Viv: Whatever works and makes sense, so you're right in principle. I am especially with you that implementing INPC on the model makes sense in many cases and is absolutely valid... It's always a tradeoff. I stick to explicit implementation of the ViewModels and accept that I have some no-brain - not duplicate (!) - code for the benefit of a clean separation of concerns. I've made a lot of good experience with this, as in almost every case in my software the ViewModel holds UI specific methods, data and metadata which definitely don't belong in the model.

Comment: @Marc I use MEF. ClientInfoModel have Import attribute set to initialize. ( i have edited the code in relevant). But still i get throw the NPE. But anyway i have changed all of my code to flat model as you have suggested. But i am still intrigued to see how make my earlier approach work.